Reincarnation/revenge manga in which the main character is killed and returned to the past in a future where a video game became reality
I was only able to read up to the 10th chapter. It was in color, and I read it a year or two ago.
Main details:

The main character (MC) is male.
The MC has a sister who he wanted to protect but couldn't.
A video game came into reality and its players received all the stats, levels, items, and skills that they had in the game.
The MC dies after a high level player kills him and his sister.
The MC returns to the past and begins playing the game to get stronger to protect his sister. He also advises his sister to play the game.

Side details:

The MC knows all the secret items and locations and how to get them.
The MC tries to get a thing in the game known as ki, which you can only get after reaching max proficiency in the most suitable weapon for you (he spent most his time in the training grounds).
The MC trains a few people that were interested.

That's all I can remember. Sorry if it's not much, but it's the best I can do.

Was this colour or black-and-white?  When did you read it?

sorry i was asleep but if i remember correctly it had color and i read it last read it a year or two from today

This is It All Starts With Playing Game Seriously.

Even a nobody should aim for the moon and have big ambitions. The game is far from over, and anybody can be a dark horse. The game, Metaverse, became a reality, where players obtained in-game abilities of their characters, throwing the world into chaos. Liu Yi, remarkably endurant, highly competitive, yet afraid of confrontation, reincarnated and returned to the world before Metaverse descended. With the knowledge he gained in his past life, he started to play the game seriously while overcoming his fear of confrontation. In the end, he would grow into a hero and save the world.


In the year 2030, a video game called Metaverse was launched. 34 days later, the game became reality and the players were granted their game characters' abilities. The world fell into chaos as the players fought one another over power and money.
The protagonist, Liu Yi, was an orphan living with his younger sister, Liu Yun. He chose to be a casual player of the game so that he could work hard to take good care of Liu Yun. As a result, when the game became reality, his stats were only at level 1 and he wasn't strong enough to protect her or himself when they were attacked and killed by two level 20 players.



He then wakes up back on the day the game first launched and vows to become a top level player within 34 days so he can protect Liu Yun this time. He decides that the first thing he needs to do is obtain qi energy by training to reach 100% proficiency with whichever weapon fits him best.



He spends the first few days practicing with steel weapons in a training area and achieves 100% proficiency with all 18 of them, but is not granted qi energy. He finally obtains it after achieving 100% proficiency with a handgun.
Later, a friend of Liu Yun's convinces her to join the game and he advises both of them to practice with weapons in the same training area he did to obtain qi energy.
You can read the manhua at WebNovel.
